# Sync contacts from iPhone to Gmail

Tags: iphone, ios, data-synchronization, contacts, gmail

I cannot sync contacts from my iPhone to my Gmail account. I have a standard Google account setup in my Mail, Contacts, Calendars settings (Exchange is not available to me). Also, my Gmail is set as my default account.

Note, my contacts are synced from Gmail to my iPhone, but not in reverse; meaning, any contact I add on my phone never makes in into my Gmail contacts. I'd like to **not** have to do this manually or through iTunes.

Answer (score 5):

Check your default contacts account on your iPhone by tapping through Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars. Next, under the CONTACTS section, tap on "Default Account". Finally, tap your Gmail account from the list.

Now every new contact you create on the iPhone will automatically push to your Gmail account.

Comment: Yes, new  contacts sync. But what about old contacts?

Comment: I would also like to sync all my existing contacts I created before noticing they weren't syncing. I'd rather not use a random third party app, especially one that likely won't even work due to reports of it crashing on export.

Answer (score 0):

New contacts go to iCloud account in iOS by default, but when I select ONLY the Gmail contact group in the Mail app new contacts appear in Gmail.

iPhone 5S, iOS 8.1.3